# How to understand SocketTimeout for http put?

Tags: java, sockets, http, timeout

From the javadoc of `java.net.Socket#setSoTimeout`, it says:

> ```
>   Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in
>   milliseconds.  With this option set to a non-zero timeout,
>   a read() call on the InputStream associated with this Socket
>   will block for only this amount of time.  If the timeout expires,
>   a <B>java.net.SocketTimeoutException</B> is raised, though the
>   Socket is still valid.
> ```

For a http put operation, the client may upload a huge file, that the client is always writing, and never reading data from server.

In this case, if I set the SocketTimeout for the http client, will it throw TimeoutException during uploading?

Answer (score 0):

No it won't. It may throw a timeout exception when reading the response code however. If the peer closes the connection during the upload, it will throw an IOException 'connection reset by peer'.